#  How to run Nginx and PHP on Mac OS X?

Tags: php, nginx, mac

I installed `PHP 5.3.6` on `Mac OS X 10.6` , but how can I run it with Nginx instead of Apache?

Previously I used `MAMP` with `Apache` but I would like to switch to `nginx`.

How can I install Nginx with PHP on Mac OS X?

Comment: http://henrik.nyh.se/2008/02/php-in-nginx-on-os-x

Comment: @Rafe Kettler I don't really get it, the article tells me how to install it with nginx, not how to run PHP :S

Comment: Well, hi serverfault guys! I hope you can help me :-)

Answer (score 1):

#### The built in Apache2 with Mac OSX can run PHP by just uncommenting out this line in your httpd.conf file:

`LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`

#### This won't work with Nginx

For Nginx you will have to [compile it from source](http://wiki.nginx.org/Modules) and configure your server files to use fastcgi.

You will also have to install php5-fpm or one of the old spawn-fcgi or php-cgi methods.  The PHP 5.3.6 you installed won't work with Nginx.

I would go with php-fpm and you can get [installation instructions on the wiki.](http://php-fpm.org/wiki/Documentation).